# align text to bottom of background image with size contain

Tags: javascript, css

I need text aligned to the bottom (and over the top) of a background image scaled with:

```
background-size: contain;
```

I tried scaling the text container with javascript, by matching the size of the image element:

```
var positionInfo = slide.getBoundingClientRect();
var height = positionInfo.height;
var width = positionInfo.width;

info.style.width=width + "px"
info.style.height=height + "px"
```

But I can't get the actual size of the background image, only the element is it contained by. Is there a way to get the background images exact size?

Full code:

```js
var info = document.getElementById('info');
var slide = document.getElementById('slide');


window.onresize = function(event) {
  posInfo()
};


function posInfo() {
  var positionInfo = slide.getBoundingClientRect();
  var height = positionInfo.height;
  var width = positionInfo.width;

  info.style.width=width + "px"
  info.style.height=height + "px"
}

  posInfo()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  border: 100px solid black;
  
}

#slide {
  border:2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url("http://c0177.paas1.ams.modxcloud.com/standard/8.jpg")
    no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index:3;
}

#info {
  border:2px solid yellow;
  display:block;
  z-index:3;
  background:transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

  
 #info a {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:yellow;
    padding:20px 120px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
    <div id="slide"></div>
    <div id="info"><a>Project name</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use a wrapper div element? Then the problem becomes much simpler.

Comment: The wrapper div would not have have the same height as the background image due to background-size:contain

Answer (score 0):

So, one way to accomplish what I believe you want to do is by making the `.fullscreen` class be a css grid that centers content. Then, instead of having the image being the background, you just put it in an image tag and it will mimic the `contain` style with some help from max-height. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/omnitect/pen/wxEMjG

```
<div class="fullscreen">
    <div id="slide">
      <img src="https://c0177.paas1.ams.modxcloud.com/standard/8.jpg" />
      <div id="info"><a>Project name</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, in the style, you want to modify `#info` to not have the transforms, it just needs a really basic position styling.

```
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  border: 100px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

#slide {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}

#slide img {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Note: The `calc(100vh)` is due to the `100px` border.

```
#info {
  border:2px solid yellow;
  display: block;
  z-index:3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: this almost works, but the image no longer scales proportionally when you resize by height.

Comment: just need to add img {max-width:100%} and this now works perfectly thanks!

Comment: @GarethJones. If this solution solves your problem, please mark it as correct.

Comment: can you approve the amend?